# Hadoop tasktracker failed to start

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop. I have local dir and system dir mentioned in the mapred config. The error log is saying cannot create the directory so the start up failed.

```
root@SYS-01:/etc/hadoop/conf.apt_hyperspace# ls -l /hyperspace/dfs/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mapred hadoop 4096 2013-05-24 16:25 mapred
drwxr-xr-x 5 hdfs   hadoop 4096 2013-05-24 15:45 nn
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
 <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
 <value>/hyperspace/dfs/mapred</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
 <value>SYS-01:9101</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>mapred.system.dir</name>
 <value>hdfs://hyperspace/mapred</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**Error -**

```
    2013-05-24 16:25:54,964 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = SYS-01/10.15.21.42
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2-cdh3u6
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///data/1/tmp/nightly_2013-03-20_11-32-44_3/hadoop-0.20-0.20.2+923.479-1~lucid -r efb405d2aa54039bdf39e0733cd0bb9423a1eb0a; compiled by 'root' on Wed Mar 20 13:10:08 PDT 2013
************************************************************/
2013-05-24 16:25:55,084 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-05-24 16:25:55,384 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-05-24 16:25:55,440 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-05-24 16:25:55,460 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker local dir /hyperspace/dfs/mapred error can not create directory: /hyperspace/dfs/mapred, removing from local dirs
2013-05-24 16:25:55,461 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No mapred local directories are writable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$LocalStorage.checkDirs(TaskTracker.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1633)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3940)

2013-05-24 16:25:55,462 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at SYS-01/10.195.241.242
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Is this a Pseudo cluster (single node)?

Comment: @ChrisWhite - This is a four machine cluster.

Comment: And how are you starting the services (manually, or via the cloudera manager UI)?

Comment: @ChrisWhite - Manually

Comment: Is user "mapred" the one launching the tasktracker? Your 'ls' was done with "root", so maybe...

Comment: Can you post the console snippet as to how you're manually launching (as @AlfonsoNishikawa is hinting towards)

Comment: Please post the output from 'hadoop fs -ls /hyperspace'.  I suspect your /hyperspace/dfs directory doesn't exist or isn't writable by user mapred.

Comment: Is the SafeMode off? when you open localhost:50070 you can see if SafeMode is on/off

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the permission of the directory dfs. I was running a test instance and I fixed the issue by changing the permission to 777.

Comment: Setting permissions to 777 is pretty much guaranteed to be a terrible idea, even if it appears to work because you're opening yourself up to future problems.

Comment: yeah i know it was only a testing platform so there is nothing like future problems. I was giving a suggestion only to check the permissions. I my case also it could have been other permission issues but for test purpose it was okay for the moment for me.