# cannot start tasktracker because java.lang.NullPointerException at

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I created Single node cluster using Hadoop 1.2.1 following [Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux(single node cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).However while trying to run single node cluster I found error cannot start tasktracker because java.lang.NullPointerException at.....which is shown on log file.I have read [Hadoop tasktracker failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743185/hadoop-tasktracker-failed-to-start) and [unable to start jobtracker and tasktracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839127/unable-to-start-jobtracker-and-tasktracker) however I couldn't get solution for my case.Please help me how to overcome this problem? What could be the problem is it with tasktracker.java source code? any idea I appreciate.
Tasktracker log file:

```
2014-08-26 23:20:07,380 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ubuntu/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT
STARTUP_MSG:   build =  -r ; compiled by 'dere' on Tue Aug 12 03:45:50 PDT 2014
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65
************************************************************/
2014-08-26 23:20:07,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2014-08-26 23:20:07,861 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2014-08-26 23:20:07,862 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2014-08-26 23:20:07,862 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2014-08-26 23:20:07,876 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3965)

2014-08-26 23:20:07,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

jps output

```
dere@ubuntu:~/Desktop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ jps
3165 JobTracker
3370 Jps
3086 SecondaryNameNode
2766 NameNode
2911 DataNode
```

Comment: We can't debug invisible code.

Comment: what information should I add?

Comment: I added those informations I considered may be necessary.Please help me now.Tell me what to add any time I can add.please help me!